# Can a Zen Archer monk take their bonus feats without the prerequisites?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

The selectable bonus feats for the level 1 [Zen Archer monk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo---monk-archetypes/zen-archer) include both point blank shot and precise shot:

> Bonus Feats: A zen archer’s bonus feats must be taken from the following list:
>
> Combat Ref lexes, Def lect Arrows, Dodge, Far Shot, Point-Blank Shot, Precise Shot, and Rapid Shot.

Can I select Precise Shot at level 1 without the prerequisite Point Blank Shot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk#TOC-Bonus-Feat):

> A monk need not have any of the prerequisites normally required for these feats to select them.

You can skip Point Blank Shot if you want, but remember that to take any feats after Precise Shot using non-bonus feats, you'll still need Point Blank Shot.

Comment: Yeah, the full description of virtually every feat not only lists immediate prerequisites but also every feat prereq that each prereq has, so without Point Blank Shot you'll be limited to only using your bonus feats to continue down the tree.  Although you get another bonus feat at level 2, so you can use it to get PBS and keep on keepin' on.

Comment: While the question is specific to *selecting* the feat--leaving the *using* part unasked--even just a link clarifying that selecting *and* using are both allowed without meeting a bonus feat's prerequisites *would* make the answer more useful. (At least to me, anyway.) I hope you can hunt down a reference.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Everything I can find says "You lose the ability to use a feat if you *lose* a prerequisite, and regain the ability to use it when you regain that prerequisite."  Nothing seems to govern if you didn't have the prereq in the first place.  [Stunning Fist](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/feats.html#stunning-fist) specifically calls out a monk *receives* the feat at 1st level, even though he doesn't meet the prereqs, and doesn't say anything about not being able to use it.  I'm pretty sure that while RAW doesn't seem have to mentioned this case specifically, RAI is made obvious.

Comment: @HeyICanChan (Note that if you *do* gain the prereqs and then lose them, even if you didn't need them in the first place, you can't use the feat anymore)

Comment: @thedarkwanderer That is terrible. I'm not sure that's entirely accurate, though. Although feats are always checking for prerequisites, class features aren't. Thus, *either* the class feature adds an ability but once and stops *or* the class feature is constantly adding the ability, yet the character gets no benefit beyond the first because it's trying to duplicate something already present. I dunno. Might make a good question if you can concoct a scenario, though.